# Multicast on local box

Tags: networking, multicast

I have an application I need to interface with that listens to a multicast address. I'd like to be able to run a program I've written and have it interface with the other application by multicast without having the traffic leave the box.

How can I go about setting this up and preferably doing it through software as I might need to deploy this on multiple boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Bind your socket to 127.0.0.1 for incoming data and for outfoing data join a multicast group.

P.S. why multicast and not tcp which seems to be logical?

Comment: The application I'm interfacing with only deals with multicasts, is there an easy way to get around this using a hack, such as netcat or something?

Comment: You can write a program or a script and pipe its output to a tool like emcast or mnc (multicast netcat) - google for them.